# Maximal abelian subalgebras of Lie algebras over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be the Lie algebra of a compact connected Lie group $G$. Let $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the complexification of $\mathfrak g$ and let $\mathfrak h \subset \mathfrak g_{\mathbb{C}}$ be a complex Lie subalgebra satisfying $\mathfrak h + \overline{\mathfrak h} = \mathfrak g_{\mathbb{C}}$. Suppose that $\mathfrak a \subset \mathfrak h$ is a maximal abelian Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak h$. Does it hold that $\mathfrak a + \overline{\mathfrak a}$ is a maximal abelian subalgebra of $\mathfrak g_{\mathcal C}$?

**Edit**: A nontrivial example:

> Suppose that $G$ is an even dimensional compact Lie group and suppose
>   that is endowed with a left-invariant complex structure(*). Take
>   $\mathfrak h$ as the set of all left-invariant vector fields that
>   annihilates every local holomorphic function on $G$.

(*): This kind of complex structure always exist. In Proposition 2.5 of [1](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02863632.pdf) there is a detailed characterization and in section 5.1 of [2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926224501000444) there is an easy construction.

Comment: Are $\overline{\mathfrak h}$ and $\overline{\mathfrak a}$ just $i\mathfrak h$ and $i\mathfrak a$?

Comment: No. An element $Z$ in $\mathfrak g_{\mathcal C}$ can be interpreted as something like $Z = X + iY$ with $X, Y \in \mathfrak g$. With this, we have $\overline{Z} = X - iY$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread:  I thought "$\mathfrak h \subseteq \mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$" said "$\mathfrak h \subseteq \mathfrak g$".

Comment: Dear @TorstenSchoeneberg, I edited the question with the answer to your questions. If you need more information, just ask.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the actual question is just set inside $\mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C}$, so could we not just ask this about any complex algebra, or how does it matter that it comes from a compact real one? In particular, in the title you are interested in Cartan subalgebras, but the question body now is about abelian subalgebras of the complexification -- which, unlike in the compact real case, are not necessarily CSA's.

Comment: To clarify the last point, would the (trivial) example $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{su}_2, \mathfrak{h} := \mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C} \simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C), \mathfrak{a} = \pmatrix{0 & *\\ 0& 0}$ count, even though $\mathfrak{a}$ is maximal abelian but not a CSA?

Comment: I've noticed now that the complex structure (i.e. what *is* $\overline{\mathfrak{h}}$?) does, in general, depend on $\mathfrak{g}$ and not only on its complexification. Still, I wonder whether there's reason to believe the result depends on this; and my second question is still valid because taking $\mathfrak{h}$ as the entire $\mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C}$ gives a trivial example regardless from which $\mathfrak{g}$ the complexification comes.

Comment: Now that you asked, I noticed that I should be careful about the conditions I asked about subalgebras of $\mathfrak h$. I was thinking that since $\mathfrak g$ comes from a compact Lie group that I could just ignore the difference between CSA and maximal abelian subalgebras, but your example shows otherwise.

Even though my question can be asked for complex Lie algebras, the only case that I am interested in is the one in which $\mathfrak g$ comes from a compact Lie group. I put this information so people helping me knows that $\mathfrak g$ has more properties if necessary.

Comment: Oh but wait ... In my supposed example, I think $\overline{\mathfrak{a}} = \pmatrix{0&0\\*&0}$ according to the complex structure, so actually $\mathfrak{a} +\overline{\mathfrak{a}}$ is not even a Lie subalgebra ... which would be a counterexample, but for a different reason. Sorry if I just add confusion. (It would help to clarify which of the algebras should be considered over which field exactly, cf. my comment to the answer.)

Comment: I don't understand which identification you are making here. could you be more explicit? This $\mathfrak a$ does not contain any skew-hermitian traceless matrices.

Comment: Viewing $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$ as complexification $(\mathfrak{su}_2)_\Bbb{C}$, the conjugation operation you allude to in your first comment is given by $X \mapsto -\sigma(X)^T$, where $\sigma$ is conjugation on each entry of the matrix. (Accordingly, $\mathfrak{g}$ is the fixed point set of that, the traceless skew-hermitian matrices.)  My $\mathfrak{a}$ is a maximal abelian complex subalgebra of the complex algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$, as asked for in the question. Then $\overline{\mathfrak{a}}$ is as described, and $\mathfrak{a} +\overline{\mathfrak{a}}$ is not even a subalgebra.

Comment: I think the problem with your example is that you are mixing the conjugation of the elements of the matrices with the conjugation corresponding with the complexification of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. And even then, you need to consider what happens when you with this subalgebra you founded with the identification of the complexification of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$.

Comment: I'm assuming that the identification you are using is $1 \otimes X_1 + i \otimes X_2 \in \mathfrak{su}2_\mathbb{C} \mapsto X_1 + iX_2 \in \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$. In this case you are taking $\mathfrak h = \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$ and $$\mathfrak{a} = \operatorname{span}_\mathbb{C} \left\{ 1 \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + i \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ -i & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}.$$ In this case $\overline{\mathfrak{a}} + \mathfrak{a}$ is not even a subalgebra!

Comment: Dear @TorstenSchoeneberg, please put your counter example as an answer so I can give you credit. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the answer is no, for a striking reason: In general, $\mathfrak{a} + \overline{\mathfrak{a}}$ is not even a subalgebra.

As example, take $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{su}_2$ which we can e.g. (following Wikipedia) define as the three-dimensional real Lie algebra with basis $u_1, u_2, u_3$ satisfying

$$\left[u_3, u_1\right] = 2u_2, \quad \left[u_1, u_2\right] = 2u_3, \quad \left[u_2, u_3\right] = 2u_1.$$

It is well-known that the complexification $\Bbb C\otimes\mathfrak{g}$ is isomorphic (as complex Lie algebra) to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$. Concretely, an isomorphism is given by
$$f(-\frac{i}{2}\otimes u_1 -\frac{1}{2}\otimes u_2) = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},$$
$$ f(-\frac{i}{2}\otimes u_1 +\frac{1}{2}\otimes u_2)=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},$$
$$ f(-i\otimes u_3) = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$$

One sees from this that $f$ identifies the conjugation action $a\otimes g \mapsto \bar a\otimes g$ on $\Bbb C\otimes \mathfrak{g}$ with 
$$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&-a} \mapsto \pmatrix{-\bar a&-\bar c\\-\bar b&\bar a}$$
on $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$ (and $\mathfrak{g}$ with the fixed point set of that, the traceless skew-hermitian matrices, in particular $u_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & i \\
    i & 0
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad
  u_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 &  0
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad
  u_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
    i &  0 \\
    0 & -i
  \end{pmatrix}$ ).

But then if we choose $\mathfrak{h} = \mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C}$, and $\mathfrak{a}$ as the one-dimensional algebra generated by $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ (which is maximal abelian in $\mathfrak{h}$), we have $\overline{\mathfrak{a}} = \pmatrix{0&0\\*&0}$, hence $$\mathfrak{a} + \overline{\mathfrak{a}} = \lbrace \pmatrix{0&b\\c&0}: b,c\in \Bbb C\rbrace$$
which is not closed under the Lie bracket, hence no Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C}$.

**NB.** If (in the special case $\mathfrak{h} = \mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C}$) $\mathfrak{a}$ is chosen as a *Cartan* subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C}$, in some low-dimensional examples it seems to me that $\overline{\mathfrak{a}} = \mathfrak{a}$ and hence the assertion is true. Maybe one can go from there to a case of more general $\mathfrak{h}$. However, I am not even sure if/why this should hold in the special case. (I've asked this as a new question [MSE/2756715: Are all CSA's in $\mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C}$ invariant under the conjugation action?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2756715/96384))

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry to tell I believe the answer is No.

Consider $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak{su}(2)$ and its complexification $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C} = \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$,
and $\mathfrak h= \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$. Now look at $\mathfrak a=\mathfrak{so}(2)$, the set of antisymmetric matrices in $\mathfrak g$. Then $\mathfrak a+\bar{\mathfrak a}$ is not maximal Abelian in $\mathfrak g_\mathbb C$, because it is properly contained in $\mathfrak a +\bar{\mathfrak a} + \mathbb C\begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ -i \end{pmatrix}$.   There are more example like this.

Comment: It looked like a lot of formatting got destroyed in your original post, so I edited it, hopefully without changing meaning.  The only semantic change I made was adding the missing word 'Abelian' to "$\mathfrak a + \bar{\mathfrak a}$ is not maximal in $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$".

Comment: Hmm ... I had assumed $\mathfrak{h}$ and then $\mathfrak{a}$ had to be *complex* subalgebras of $\mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C}$, which yours are are not. But then I fail to see how $\mathfrak{a} + \overline{\mathfrak{a}}$ is a complex subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C}$ at all; in your example, is the conjugation action on $\mathfrak{a}$ not just multiplication with $-1$, and hence $\mathfrak{a} = \overline{\mathfrak{a}}$? Or are we talking about $\mathfrak{g}_{\Bbb C}$ and everything inside it as *real* algebras all the time? Maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: In fact, I forgot to make it explicit that $\mathfrak h$ has to be a complex subalgebra of $\mathfrak{su}(2) \otimes \mathbb{C}$. Anyway, in this example, it does not hold that  $\mathfrak{h} + \overline{\mathfrak{h}} = \mathfrak g_{\mathbb{C}}$.